# Struggling with Using A Flow to Replace a DLRS. Why is the flow timing out?

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, dlrs

I am trying to write a flow to replace a DLRS because the DLRS is consistently reaching its query row limit when it runs. I want a field on one object (product) that sums a qty field from another object Sales Order Line Item) that are related through a look-up. Basically, I want the total amount of a product sold from the sales order line items on the product object as "Quantity Sold". The flow should run any time a sales order line item is created or updated (in case of order cancellations).

I actually have a draft flow that is working successfully in debug and test modes but only for some products. When working with some of our most popular products where there a lot of sales order line items to loop through (10K+ in some cases), the flow is taking a painfully long time to execute and in some cases appears to time out and I get this message:

[image]
What can do I to address this issue? Is there a limit to number of times a loop will execute? If so, how do I get around that? If not, what else can be done to help this flow run more smoothly?

Comment: I don't think that a flow is the right tool for the job here. Incremental counting is hard to make reliable (because things like other triggers or after-save flow field updates can get you back into the "before update" part of the Trigger Order of Operations), and doing a full count each time necessarily involves querying each child record. Do you have DLRS configured to do its work on a schedule (i.e. async)? If not, that's almost certainly the first thing you should try here.